# How do obtain permissions to install packages for Anaconda3 on Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows-10, anaconda, cherrypy, conda

I am trying to install cherrypy for anaconda3, using the following page's commands https://anaconda.org/anaconda/cherrypy, but am getting the following error message,

[image]

The operating system I am using is Windows 10 and I have checked that I have administrator privileges with my login. Moreover I installed anaconda for all users and have checked that all mmy logins can modify the C:\Program Files\Anaconda3 folder.

What should I do?

Comment: Also all sudo ... commands wont work either

Comment: umask/sudo are POSIX commands, they are meant to be run under UNIX-like OSes

Comment: @webKnjaZ thanks but are you aware how my original problem can be solved?

Comment: (I dont want to do the clone by the way)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right-click on "Start" button and choose "Command Prompt (Admin)" instead of "Command Prompt". Then run your install command.

Comment: Maybe add a link to the documentation

Comment: Another option would be to right click "Anaconda Prompt" and run as administrator from the Start menu.

Comment: the path shows `system32`. Is that ok? I dont want to install packages on some other path

Answer (score -2):

right click on anaconda3 folder in windows file explorer and give yourself full control permission. This solved it for me, hope it helps